# Contents in <td> are overlapping

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am populating a dynamically-created table that contains one `<tr>`. There is only one `<td>` in that table row. The problem is that when I load data that exceed from one line, it overlaps.

**`Style code of <td>`**

```
   D2.setAttribute('style', 'text-align:right; font-size: 40px; height:90px; vertical-align:middle');
```

[image]

Comment: that contains one one means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting in CSS:

`line-height : 25px /*as desired*/`

Comment: Easy and fast. Cool Era

Comment: She is a Genius... :-) Wts Up Era

Comment: You need to wait Era...it takes 8 minutes before to mark as answer

Comment: @Era I am also Happy.. :)

Comment: @Era I support Nilesh argument ... :D

Comment: @Era Everybody is fond of Era, question should be who is Era fond of?